# Webmate Textmate Plugin for Textmate 2.0

Tags: macos, html, plugins, web-development, textmate-2

I downloaded the new version of Textmate last night (v 2.0 build 9515).  I tried to load it with the Webmate plugin which allows you to display HTML pages that your coding in a preview window and it will allow you to see changes as you make them within the code (without about a 1 second delay).  But when I try to load it in Textmate 2.0 it says its not compatible.

Is there any way to get it to work?  Or any good alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't update immediately as you type but I found a project on Github which I'm happy with.  It displays the HTML page in a preview window and displays changes quickly each time you save the file (Cmd+S).  https://github.com/gknops/HTML-ApLo.tmbundle

Instructions on installing the bundle and a single dependency it requires are detailed in the Readme.